# Limiting a character after a wildcard in regex to it's first occurrence,

Tags: regex, wildcard

How can I tell a character that comes after a wildcard to use the first occurrence of it?

I did the following to find any tag with the word "title" in it:

`<(.*?)(title)(.*?)>`

but clearly what happens is I end up with the entire tag to the end of

`</title>`

So that in

`<Bla bla ="nametitle">Yada yada</title>`

I want

`<Bla bla ="nametitle">`

but end up with the whole tag.

Please if anyone is offended by the use of parsing html with regex simply move on and accept my apologies for the transgression. I am simply trying to find out how to use the wildcard which I have not used before correctly and apply as I see fit. Thank you.

Comment: `<(.*?)(title)(.+?)>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
<title.+?>
```

The above matches `<title` and goes till it encounters a `>`

Answer (score 0):

Stop parsing at the first `>`. Using your example, you could do this with: `<(.*?)(title)([^>]*?)>`

Comment: I lose my entire match then. Basically I am using the wildcard title tag to find specific text inside those named tags. If I use the brackets then all my subsequent matches disappear.

Answer (score 0):

`<(?![\/]).*?title.*?>`

This will find `title` inside any set of `< >` tags except for closing tags beginning with `</`

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/QFs4ny/1